# How to use ImageButton state_focused?

Tags: android, selector, imagebutton

## my xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentSelectorArea"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/main_seletor_height"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_seletor_margin_bottom"
    android:background="@color/mainBtnBg" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_btn_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector" />
</LinearyLayout>
```

## btn_selector.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_btn" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/focused_btn" />    
<item android:drawable="@drawable/nonselected_btn"/>
```

## activity.java

```
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
OnClickListener btnListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View btn) {
        switch (btn.getId()) {
        case R.id.myBtn:
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            break;
        ...
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
btn1.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
```

I want to use effect when I clicked buttons.

### normal(no focused), focused, pressed<-

But the state_focused is not working.
So I can't see focused effect.
Please help me..

add image.
[image]

Comment: You won't see focused state when you click the button. You will instead see it when you hover over the button (possibly in your emulator). Read this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852420/what-is-the-state-focused-state-for-a-button

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852420/what-is-the-state-focused-state-for-a-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

button selector just two case. (pressed, non-pressed)
I overriding onPageChangeListener() in ViewPagerIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

`state_focused` applied whenever the button is focused on using a `dpad` or the `trackball`. Views don't generally show a focused state when using touch.

Comment: But I want to use three buttons effect. any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by three buttons effect?

Comment: @SaeHyunKim Can you explain more? What do you mean by a three buttons effect?

Comment: oh sorry. one button -> three effect
focused(current state), pressed, non-pressed(usual)

Comment: i guess it's not possible because you won't get the focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setonTouchListener to create an effect on the touch of your ImageButton like ...

```
    myBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                myBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.quit_yes_selected);
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                myBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.quit_yes);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Or you ca simply create an btn_selector.xml file in your drawable and set that to your ImageBackgroundResource like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, you should use bg with grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_btn"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, you should use bg with white -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nonselected_btn" />
</selector>
```

And in the java you have to assign your ImageButton background resource as that file

```
myBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_selector);
```

Comment: Just two effect(pressed, non-selected). But I want three effect! T.T