# Why Button with Background gets no focus when pressed in android?

Tags: android, button, focus

Here is a button with background that gets no focus when touch it.
Here is the xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/continueID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbg"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:onClick="invokeLogin"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#F7F9FA" />
```

Comment: Maybe it is focused, but the background do not have a different image for focused state.

Comment: Check in your activity class if the button is gaining focus while pressing.

Comment: i am not write any code for gaining focus in activity class, because i dont know what i write here for focus @Akeshwar

Comment: by default, the click works for the button, but it isn't shown focused. If you want to change the appearance of the button after it gains focus, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852420/what-is-the-state-focused-state-for-a-button

Answer (score 0):

'buttonbg' background must handle the focused state so you can see changes when you touch it.

For example:-

```
// buttonbg.xml 

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_imagename_while_focused"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_imagename_while_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_name_while_notpressed" />  //means normal
</selector>
```

Comment: I Have no image for Pressed, then what i should do? @Omar Albelbaisy

Comment: You should create one to to reflect the change that must happen when you press the button, because when you set the background you override the default button background which implements all the states you see when you interact with the button

Comment: you can come in chat? @Omar Albelbaisy